# Highcharts prevent xAxis Labels hidden

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts to display a bar graph.  I have a fixed vertical height for the chart, and I want all xAxis labels to be displayed.  The horizontal portion of the webparts container is responsive to the size of the window.  I have found at certain horizontal sizes the legend wraps which appears to cause some of my xAxis labels to hidden.  I have been unable to find any setting or combination of settings that will prevent this.  Does anyone know a way to make this possible without changing the vertical height of the webpart?

Example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbm6q/1/) of issue.

or sample code below,

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 180px; width: 330px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="container2" style="height: 180px; width: 500px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4', 'Data5']
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name:'Due > 7',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0]
        },{
            name:'Due < 7',
            data: [34.9, 72.1, 99.4, 150.4, 169.1]
        },{
            name:'Overdue < 7',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0]
        },{
            name:'Overdue > 7',
            data: [34.9, 72.1, 99.4, 150.4, 169.1]
        }]
    };
    $('#container').highcharts(options);
    $('#container2').highcharts(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redesign a little chart, some solutions:

- use legend on a right side: http://jsfiddle.net/Sbm6q/2/
- set `maxHeight` for a chart (may not work in your case, when you have so little number of series): http://jsfiddle.net/Sbm6q/3/

Comment: maxHeight appears to be the best option in my case.  Thank you for the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the step option, and set his value to one. (documentation: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.step )

In my project, this resolved the xAxis label that are been hidden by highcharts, because the API hidden elements that will be overwrite other because lack of space. So, when I used this, all xAxis values are shown, but a few overwrite the next label. So, I have to extend my graph heigth.

But worked, it is pretty good responsive now!